# Derivation of cutoff frequency and phase shift for RC low pass filter

Tags: filter, signal-processing, low-pass, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

I've been having some problems with how to find the cutoff frequency and the phase shift for a simple RC low pass filter circuit.

I've read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140553/how-do-i-calculate-the-cutoff-frequency-of-a-low-pass-rc-circuit) post, but I need a better understanding of what frequency response to fully be able to understand it.

So how is it that the cutoff frequency is \$f_c=\frac{1}{2\pi R C}\$? And how can I derive the phase shift being -\$\arctan(\omega RC)\$ ?

Comment: What are these "some problems" specifically? Look at my answer to the question (the 2nd one) and does what I say in the first line mean anything to you? Quote: "For a simple RC low pass filter, cut-off (3dB point) is defined as when the resistance is the same magnitude as the capacitive reactance"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand about your solution, is how did you get to R=1/(2πFC)?

Comment: Do you know what the reactive impedance of a capacitor is (common called capacitive reactance)?

Comment: Yea I do. And I just realized I'm stupid. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Learning usually starts with stupidity but can sometimes involve it along the way at several points. Always best to be honest with yourself LOL.

Answer (score 5):

Cut-off frequency or 3-dB frequency is defined as the frequency of the input signal at which, the magnitude of the output signal reduces to \$1/\sqrt2\$ of the input, or the power reduces to half ( i.e., by 3 dBs).

A simple RC circuit:
[image]

$$V_{out} = V_{in}. \frac {-jX_c}{R-jX_c}$$

By our above definition, at cut-off frequency \$f_o\$ , \$ \frac {-jX_c}{R-jX_c} \$ should be equal to \$1/\sqrt2\$

i.e.,
$$\frac{-jX_c}{R -jX_c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $$
taking magnitude of the complex expression:
$$=> \frac {X_c}{\sqrt {R^2+X_c^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $$
$$ => \frac {1}{\sqrt{(R^2/X_c^2)+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $$
$$ => (R^2/X_c^2) = 1 $$
$$ => R = X_c $$
$$ => R = \frac{1}{Cw_o}$$
$$ => w_o = \frac {1}{RC}$$
$$ => f_o = 1/2 \pi RC$$

for complex numbers, phase of \$a+ jb = tan^{-1}(b/a)\$ , \$V_{out}\$ is a complex expression, Hence its phase \$ \phi \$ would be:
$$ \angle \frac {tan^{-1}(-\infty)}{tan^{-1}(-X_c/R)} $$
$$ = \angle\frac {-tan^{-1}\infty}{-tan^{-1}(X_c/R)}   $$
$$ = -\frac{\pi}{2} + tan^{-1}(X_c/R) $$
using the expression, \$ tan^{-1}x + tan^{-1}(1/x) = \pi/2 \$
$$ => \phi =  -tan^{-1}(R/X_c) = -tan^{-1}(wRC)$$

Comment: I'm not rally sure where you got this from: 
∠tan−1(−α)/tan−1(−Xc/R)

And what excatly is α? Thanks

Comment: The real part = 0, imaginary part is -Xc. So phase is tan inverse of -infinity.  I don't how to write " infinity ". So I put alpha symbol... :D

Comment: In your question, you are missing a  -ve symbol in the expression for phase. It is there actually. Check wiki link :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit

Comment: This might be of [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192849/redefining-infinity-in-latex/192867).